# maven javadoc:aggregate artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: maven, javadoc

I wanted to run `mvn javadoc:aggregate -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none` on a multimodule project where `mvn javadoc:javadoc -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none` works just fine.

But it returnes

> An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved:

Those dependencies are declared in a submodule that also declares the specific repositories. The dependencies are already cached in the local .m2.

How can I get `aggregate` to find them?

---

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0-M1:aggregate (default-cli) on project bigspatialdata-parent: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0-M1:aggregate (default-cli) on project bigspatialdata-parent: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred in Javadoc report generation: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.failOnError(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:5954)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocReport.doExecute(JavadocReport.java:322)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.execute(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:1889)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.getClasspath(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2598)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.addJavadocOptions(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:4582)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2028)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocReport.generate(JavadocReport.java:130)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocReport.doExecute(JavadocReport.java:318)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven31DependencyResolverException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven31DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven31DependencyResolver.java:251)
at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven31DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven31DependencyResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:62)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.getClasspath(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2579)
... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven31DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven31DependencyResolver.java:227)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-api:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:17.2, org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:17.2: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 in repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
... 33 more
```

Comment: This is the simpler problem of artifact resolution in maven and has nothing to do with javadoc.  If I can find [org.geotools:gt-main:jar:17.2 on mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-main/17.2), then you need to add mvnrepository.com to the list of repositories or make your repository act as a forwarder for artifacts it cannot resolve on its own.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand your answer. The repositories are declared like this in  the submodule:
`[...]
      <url>http://geowave-maven.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
[...]
      <url>https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/</url>
[...]
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
[...] `

Comment: Have you verified that this particular library is contained within one of the listed repositories?  Does this library already reside locally in your .m2 folder?

Comment: yes they are in the repositories and they are available locally in .m2

Comment: I can't help but notice that your geowave repository is disabled.  I'm guessing that is the source for your geotools library?  You could give that a try.  Otherwise, if it is as you say, I can't help you.